# Dynamically add span tag to link inside <ng-content></ng-content>

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom list-item component with `<ng-content>` as the template:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: '[my-list-item]',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class MyListItemComponent {
    @Input() active = false; 
}
```

the user can set the active state.

```
<ul>
    <li my-list-item [active]="true">
        <a href="#">Stackoverflow</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

if the active flag is set to true, i have to add a custom span tag inside the link and it should be rendered like that:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="active">Stackoverflow</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What's the recommended way in angular2 to accomplish this?
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leverage the following approach:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'li>a' })
export class MyAnchorDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private rendered: Renderer) { }
  public wrapContent() {
    var el = this.elRef.nativeElement;
    this.rendered.setElementProperty(el, 'innerHTML', 
       `<span class="active">${el.innerHTML}</span>`);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: '[my-list-item]',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class MyListItemComponent {
  @Input() active = false;
  @ContentChild(MyAnchorDirective) anchor: MyAnchorDirective;
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.active && this.anchor) {
      this.anchor.wrapContent();
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li my-list-item [active]="true">
          <a href="#">Stackoverflow</a>
      </li>
      <li my-list-item [active]="false">
          <a href="#">Stackoverflow2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/I9Ucyyr3I7omF6epqpd8?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Set a div inside, then set any div content

```
<ul>
  <li my-list-item [active]="true">
    <a href="#"><div id='you_can_do_it_in_a_div'>Stackoverflow</div></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
document.getElementById('you_can_do_it_in_a_div').innerHTML = 'whatever';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Not tested.*

Your placeholder should be like

```
<ng-content *ngIf="active"></ng-content>
```

in main html file

Modify component to be

```
    import Component from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: '[my-list-item]',
        template: `
               <ul>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">
                           <span class="active">Stackoverflow</span>
                       </a>
                  </li>
             </ul>
        `
    })
    export class MyListItemComponent {
        active = false; 
    }
```

be careful about template syntax, it is  backtick (`)—which is not the same character as a single quote (')—allows you to compose a string over several lines, which makes the HTML more readable.

Why are you importing Input by the way?